# Available chromedriver is not working on 64-bit Mac

Tags: macos, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use chromedriver on a 64-bit mac, but haven't been successful yet. I keep getting error "Cannot execute binary file". The permissions are all correct and I don't see any other missing piece either. I am not sure if the available 32-bit version for mac would actually work on 64-bit mac.

Any help on this would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on my 64 bit MacOS. Turns out when I downloaded the zip file (mac_32.zip) from download page, and extracted the file from it, and then moved to the the directory where I wanted it to be... MacOS had created shortcut for me. Once I killed shortcut and made sure the target directory contains the real file, the problem went away.